# Can't find curl or sudo package in a ubuntu pod

Tags: ubuntu, curl, kubernetes, sudo, apt-get

I deployed a service on kubernetes and then I wanted to test it out inside the cluster itself, before I put an ingress rule to access it outside.

So, after I verified from the log that the service is running.

I tried to create a pod and get to the shell in it via

`kubectl run -i --tty ubuntu --image=ubuntu --restart=Never -- sh`

This seems to work fine. I am shown an ubuntu shell, and it seems to work fine.

But then if I do a curl: example

`curl --location --request GET 'http://127.0.0.1:9000/hello'`

I get a response
`sh: 4: curl: not found`

So then I tried,

`apt-get install curl`
which gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package curl
```

Thought this was because of sudo. so I did `sudo apt-get install curl`, but that tells me
`sh: 6: sudo: not found`

Tried installing sudo with `apt-get install sudo` but that just gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sudo
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It does. I also did answer my own question after I did find the answer myself from other sources. (not sure why my google foo was not good enough).

Comment: Then please accept the duplicate nominations. Duplicate questions are a problem because they fragment the knowledge on a particular topic; having your question closed as a duplicate will help those who use the terms in your question find it better in Google going forward, while still showing them where to find the properly peer-reviewed answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems I just needed to update apt-get.

It seems when you do get into such a pod, you are working in as root user. Just do `apt-get update`  and then later you can do `apt-get install curl`. And that works.

And if yours is an alpine one, instead of apt, it would be

`apk add curl`